# SQL Server database restore with CDC using SQL Management Objects in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, smo, cdc

I am restoring a full database backup from our production server to our staging server using the Restore class in SQL Management Objects, via a C# script task in SSIS.  The database I am restoring is a CDC enabled database with a number of change tables - however these tables are being dropped once the restore has completed.  I know that there is a KEEP_CDC option in the TSQL Restore command but I can't seem to find an equivalent property in SMO.  Is there a way that I can do the restore using SMO whilst retaining the CDC capture instance?  This is my code:

```
               Server srv;

            srv = new Server();

            //kill all connections to the database prior to restore
            srv.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);

            Restore res = new Restore();

            res.Database = databaseName;
            res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            res.Devices.AddDevice(filePath, DeviceType.File);
            res.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            res.ReadFileList(srv);

            DataTable filelist = res.ReadFileList(srv);

            foreach (DataRow row in filelist.Rows)
            {
                string logicalFileName = Path.GetFileName(row["LogicalName"].ToString());
                string physicalFileName = Path.GetFileName(row["PhysicalName"].ToString());

                switch (Path.GetFileName(row["Type"].ToString()))
                {
                    case "D":
                        res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalFileName, Path.Combine(DataFilePath, physicalFileName)));
                        break;

                    case "L":
                        res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalFileName, Path.Combine(LogFilePath, physicalFileName)));
                        break;

                }
            }

            res.SqlRestore(srv);
```

Comment: No, SMO has no support for this. This is trivially established by decompiling the assemblies and checking the implementation of the `Restore.Script` method -- `KEEP_CDC` is never added to the command anywhere. This is true even for the [most recent version available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/150.18068.0-preview).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.